# Links to Linked and Related questions in mobile mode

Tags: feature-request

Why doesn’t the question page in the mobile mode (for screens with a narrow width) show the *Linked* and *Related* sections? I can understand why they cannot be displayed on the right side as in the PC mode, but the mobile mode does show some of the other information that is displayed on the right side in the PC mode in the lower part of the page, such as *Feature on Meta*, *Hot Meta Posts*, and even *Hot Network Questions*, which are totally irrelevant to the question being asked.

If there is a way to jump to linked questions, I would like to know.

Comment: It seems this feature is available now.